# In Mockito, Is there any way to mock Class (instead of interface) which have method that need to mocked and method that need to be tested?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I was trying to mock the class which has the method

```java
public double add(double in1, double in2)
```

and

```java
@Test
public void test()
```

when I run code, I got an error

```
**Wanted but not invoked:
calculator.add(10.0, 20.0);
-> at main.Calculator.test(Calculator.java:20)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.**
```

Please find the screenshot of the code.

[image: Calculator class having a public void test() and public double add()]

[image: TestCalculator class containing main() . Where I am getting below o/p on console]

```
Jul 24, 2020 11:48:05 PM main.TestCalculator main
INFO: test(main.Calculator): 
**Wanted but not invoked:
calculator.add(10.0, 20.0);
-> at main.Calculator.test(Calculator.java:20)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.**

Jul 24, 2020 11:48:05 PM main.TestCalculator main
INFO: Result: false
```

Comment: Your verify statement should be at the end after assert statement.

Comment: What is the purpose of your test ? The method implementation which you want to test is itself mocked ?

Comment: @Mensur Qulami 

 I tried to add verify statement at the end after the assert,
But logger inside add(double in1, double in2) method "mocking" not printed on the console.
Output is 


"Jul 26, 2020, 10:43:39 PM main.TestCalculator main
INFO: Result: true
"

The purpose of testing is to check if we can have a mocked object and method to be tested inside the same class. (I don't want to use interface and SpringBoot annotations)

Comment: @PrashantChinchkar you probably tagged the wrong user.

Answer (score 0):

Your `verify` statement should come *after* the method you are verifying has been invoked.  In this case, you are trying to verify that the `add` method was invoked, but that method isn't called before your verify statement.

You should put your test code in a different class separate from the class you are testing.  So your Calculator class should have a corresponding CalculatorTests class that contains just the unit tests.

Check out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_spying.htm for info on Mockito `spy` which allows you to mock one method of a class you are testing, but make a real call for some *other* method on the same class.